# How do I write a bash script to compile multiple files containing spaces?

Tags: bash, shell-script, g++

This is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=~/Desktop/cpp/$1/*
mkdir ~/Desktop/cpp/$1o 
for f in $FILES
do
    echo $(basename $f) >>  ~/Desktop/cpp/$1err.log
    g++ '"'$f'"' -std=c++11 -o '"'~/Desktop/cpp/$1o/$(basename "$f").out'"' 2>>  ~/Desktop/cpp/$1err.log
done
```

If I don't use '"' parts, then the script works fine for files without spaces. With them, it says:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file /dirname/-
x.out: No such file or directory
```

How do I add quotation marks around the file name so that spaces are supported?

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the variables with double quotes, not `'"'` literal double quote strings, just plain `"$f"` double quotes. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) for all the gory details.

And I'd use more variables to reduce duplication.

Try this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cppdir="$HOME/Desktop/cpp/$1"
if [[ ! -d "$cppdir" ]]; then
    echo "No such directory" >&2
    exit 1
fi

outdir="${cppdir}o"
mkdir -p "$outdir"

errlog="${cppdir}err.log"

for f in "$cppdir"/*; do
    b=$(basename "$f")
    printf '%s\n' "$b" >> "$errlog"
    g++ "$f" -std=c++11 -o "$outdir/$b.out" 2>> "$errlog"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using "s first, but it didn't work. Your code works though. I'm not sure why. I wrote: `g++ "$f" -std=c++11 -o "~/Desktop/cpp/$1o/$(basename "$f").out" 2>>  ~/Desktop/cpp/$1err.log`

Comment: When you put the tilde inside quotes, it doesn't expand.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way is to use `find` and `xargs` with a `NUL`-character as delimiter:

```
outdir="$1"o
mkdir "$outdir"
errlog="$1"err.log
touch "$errlog"

find ~/Desktop/cpp/"$1"/ -type f -name '*.cpp' -print0 |
  xargs -0 -I source bash -c "echo source >> $errlog &&
    g++ source -std=c++11 -o source.out 2>> $errlog"
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't tried checking extensions yet.